# Is there a way to track mobile data usage without a "billing cycle"?

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring

The stock data manager is so complicated, with its monthly billing cycle. I have a prepaid data plan which doesn't expire. I want to set a data limit, and after that limit is hit, no matter in how many days, it simply stops data until a new limit is set, and then it starts counting from zero again.

Is there a way to achieve this?